# Excel Macro- How to delete cell values after a row number?

Tags: vba, excel

Columns A to K have entries till a specific number which may vary. Columns L to Q have entries till 1,50,000. I want to delete all entries after the last entry in Column A (this number is variable)

The code that I got after recording macro is given below.

The issue with the code is that it is hardcoding 
Application.Goto Reference:="R70086C1"

```
Sub ExtraDelete()
    ' ExtraDelete Macro
    Range("AN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-39], ""*"")"
    Range("AN1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AN3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AN1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto Reference:="R70086C1"
    Rows("70087:70087").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A70082").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to delete all the rows below the last value in Column A?

Comment: Yes. Columns A to K have entries till a specific number which may vary. Columns L to Q have entries till 1,50,000. I want to delete all entries after the last entry in Column A.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>I want to delete all entries after the last entry in Column A.</sub>

Typically, you would start at the bottom on column A and look up to find the last populated cell. It's like starting at A1048576 and tapping ctrl+<up arrow>.

Range.Select is almost never needed and rarely the best method. ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251))

```
Sub ExtraDelete()
    ' ExtraDelete Macro

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        .range(.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0), _
               .cells(.rows.count, "A")).entirerow.clear
        .parent.Save
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: The .offset(1,0) moves down one row from the last populated cell in column A.

Comment: I want to delete from the last entry in Column A (lets call it X)

AX: Q150000

Will the code be able to do that?

Comment: No worries, that was a potentially a big error. You should probably test code you get from the internet on a copy of the original.

Comment: Alright.
I have another issue. Please be kind enough to resolve this as well.

Comment: The below code does not work. I am trying to create a pivot with average of Hrs and I don't want the value 0 to be considered in the average.

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AnalyticsPivotTable").PivotFields("Hrs")

    .Orientation = xlDataField

    .Position = 2

    .Function = "=Average If(M:M,"">0"")"

  .NumberFormat = "#,##0"

Comment: That would be a new question with new sample data, expected results and (hopefully) showing some original effort.

Comment: I have to wait another 90 mins apparently to ask a question. I am new to this site and therefore do not know the way around. But I needed the answer so thought I'll ask you

Comment: Well, I could answer slower in the future so you don't have to wait so long :) Why don't you get started collecting up everything you need so you will be prepared to submit a great question?